# Shared memory and memcpy issue

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap, memcpy

I'm learning to program with shared memory in C (linux). I need to share some struct among several process that will be created with fork(). Unfortunately, when i'm trying to initialize the newly shared address space i get a slient error (no output in console) at the memcpy call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define ROWS 10000
#define COLS 15000

struct mm_shared {
    int test;
    unsigned char matrix[ROWS][COLS];
};

int main(void) {

    int fd;
    if ((fd = shm_open("/mm", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777)) == -1) {
        printf(stderr, "shm_open failed! %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    if (ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct mm_shared) == -1)) {
        printf(stderr, "ftruncate failed! %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    struct mm_shared * shared;
    if ((shared = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct mm_shared), PROT_READ
            | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == -1) {
        printf("mmap failed! %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    struct mm_shared * init = (struct mm_shared *) malloc(sizeof(struct mm_shared));

    memcpy(shared, init, sizeof(struct mm_shared)); <-- here lies the problem!


    shm_unlink("/mm");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When debugging the shared pointer, the debug info (eclipse debugger) shows:

```
Failed to execute MI command:
-data-evaluate-expression (shared)->test
Error message from debugger back end:
Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffff7ffc000
```

I don't know if this may help. Also, i would like to ask if my approach of storing a big matrix inside the struct is right (it should be allocated in the heap right? because i get a pointer to the struct even when the matrix itself isn't a pointer).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that the data returned by `malloc()` is not initialized, so you're attempting to copy uninitialized data over the shared data.  Of itself, that shouldn't cause a crash.  You're allocating around 150 MiB for the structure, and presumably that much shared memory.  You should certainly verify that the `malloc()` succeeded, though it would be a bit surprising to find a desktop machine where that failed.

Comment: You need to compile with more warnings.  You omitted `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<unistd.h>` and `<sys/mman.h>` from the headers.  When they're provided, the compiler tells you that you should not be using `printf(stderr, …`; presumably, you meant `fprintf(stderr, …`.  When you plough through that lot, and get the comparison between `shared` and `-1` fixed (`== (void *)-1` works — `mmap()` returns a void pointer), then the code compiles.  I get `mmap failed! 22, Invalid argument` followed by a core dump because the code continues after a failure message.

Comment: POSIX.1 says [`mmap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) will return `MAP_FAILED` (which *should* be equal to `(void *)-1`) with `errno` set if an error occurs. At minimum, I'd expect a `return EXIT_FAILURE;` in the error case. Furthermore, although technically the `length` of the mapping does not need to be aligned to (rounded up to next multiple of) `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)`, it is recommended to do so (to avoid rounding bugs in the kernel or C library).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, they help improving my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an hour of debugging and review cycles found the error finally, and its this

> ```
> second argument for ftruncate seems to be evaluating to wrong value
> ```

```
if (ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct mm_shared) == -1)) {
```

Changed to

```
if (ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct mm_shared)) == -1) {
```

Here is code with alterations

```
int main(void) {

    int fd;
    if ((fd = shm_open("/mm", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "shm_open failed! %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); // should be fprintf
    exit(1);// possibly exit here
    }

    //if (ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct mm_shared) == -1)) {
    if (ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct mm_shared)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ftruncate failed! %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); // should be fprintf
    goto out;   // remove all before leaving    
    }

    struct mm_shared * shared;
    if ((shared = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct mm_shared) , PROT_READ
            | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED ) {  // Change -1 to MAP_FALED
        fprintf(stderr, "mmap failed! %d, %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); // should be fprintf and stderr 
    goto out;   // remove all before leaving
    }
    struct mm_shared * init = (struct mm_shared *) malloc(sizeof(struct mm_shared));

    //memcpy(shared, init, sizeof(struct mm_shared)); //<-- here lies the problem!
    memcpy(init, shared, sizeof(struct mm_shared)); //<-- here lies the problem!

out:
    shm_unlink("/mm");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Oh god! I'm truly sorry for doing that! Many thanks!! :) I seriously doubt if i would be able to spot that on my own...